# com.apple.xpc.launchd Report crash process constantly shows up with high CPU

Tags: macos, crash

There is a process »Crash Report« in the Activity Monitor which uses 10-25% and constantly disappears and shows up again. When I quit it from the activity monitor it comes back right away. Also, the MacBook fan is going crazy. In the systemlog I see this entry several times per second:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (secagntd) Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (secagntd) Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
```

There are lot of Crash Reports in the OS X Console. The Crashlog looks like this:

```
Process:               secagntd [1030]
Path:                  /usr/local/bin/secagntd/secagntd
Identifier:            secagntd
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           secagntd [1030]
User ID:               0

Date/Time:             2016-07-31 19:15:25.985 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1909)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        75C82E52-67A5-8A7F-56CA-FB9B99BB5C0E


Time Awake Since Boot: 2900 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _wlScanBSSID
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/secagntd/libwpsapi.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Apple80211
 in /usr/local/bin/secagntd/libwpsapi.dylib
```

Which application uses the secagntd process? How do I get rid of these Crash reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that »CleanMyMac« hasn’t completely removed all leftovers. We’ve got rid of »CleanMyMac« and manually removed the »secagntd« directory in /usr/local/bin/secagntd. Usually I don’t recommend to do any modification in /usr/local/bin, however in our case it solved the issue. CPU dropped and the constantly Crash Reports disappeared.